# excel ace.oledb vba connection to csv returning only first column

Tags: sql, excel, vba, csv

In VBA Excel (Office 365) trhough using a connection string like `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=..."` and using the command string  `SELECT * FROM [text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;Delimiter=';';database=KKS].[kks.csv];` the results are:
[image] when the CSV source looks like this:

```
rng;key;component;
"0";"A";"Grid and distribution systems";
"0";"B";"Power transmission and auxiliary power supply";
```

The `schema.ini` is:

```
[kks.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=CSVDelimited
Decimalsymbol=(,)
Delimiter=(;)
```

I have tried any combination for the connection string and for schema.ini (also removing it completely) and the results are the same at best. Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you post the full code that connects and retrieves the data. Presumably the Schema file is in the same folder as the csv?

Comment: The code reduced like this:
    `
    Set oCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set oRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    oRs.cursorlocation = 2 '// 1 = adUseNone; 2 = adUseServer; 3 = adUseClient
    
`
and next:
The whole connection string looks like this:     `sCnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path() & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.name() & ";" & _
              "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
` then
`    
    Call oRs.Open(sCdStr, oCn, -1, 1)
` and this must be ok. Many thanks!

Comment: A note: I don't want to change the parameters of the Recordset.Open() - is a working code and basically cannot be modified. The solution must apply to connection string and schema.ini only. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the Schema.ini as below.

```
[kks.csv]
Format = Delimited(;)
```

Comment: This was. Now it works. Thank you very much!